# Spatial Adjustment - ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, spatial-adjustment

I want to select an edge of parcel instead of `creating multiple displacement links`.
The problem is when selecting the parcel, and the edge of the parcel contains vertices, the links that will be attached to the parcel edge will cover the area between two vertices,
How to attache the links among all the parcel edge, regardless the number of the vertices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In editing mode within the polygon feature template there is a [Auto-Complete Polygon](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m60000002r000000) tool.